# In python using iloc how would you retrive the last 12 values of a specific column in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So the problem I seem to have is that I want to acces the data in a dataframe but only the last twelve numbers in every column so I have a data frame:

```
index   A   B   C
  20    1   2   3
  21    2   5   6 
  22    7   8   9 
  23    10  1   2
  24    3   1   2
  25    4   9   0
  26    10  11  12
  27    1   2   3
  28    2   1   5
  29    6   7   8
  30    8   4   5 
  31    1   3   4
  32    1   2   3
  33    5   6   7
  34    1   3   4
```

The values inside A,B,C are not important they are just to show an example
currently I am using

```
 df1=df2.iloc[23:35]
```

perhaps there is an easier way to do this because I have to do this for around 20 different dataframes of different sizes  I know that if I use

```
df1=df2.iloc[-1]
```

it will return the last number but I dont know how to incorporate it for the last twelve numbers. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last n rows of a DataFrame by:

```
df.tail(n)
```

or

```
df.iloc[-n-1:-1]
```

Comment: Thank you very Ha Bom much that's exactly what i needed